# React useRef to target specific div?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I have this modal that is wrapped with an entire background div. My issue is that I added a close function on the background, so no matter where I click, it will close the modal.

I would like to have the useRef only target the background div and not work if I click any of the children inside of it

Here is the code

```
const modalRef = useRef();

const closeModal = e => {
  if (modalRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
    setShowModal(false);
  }
}

return (
  <>
    {showModal ? (
      <Background onClick={closeModal} ref={modalRef}>
        <animated.div style={animation}>
          <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
            <div>hi</div>
            <CloseModalButton
              aria-label='Close modal'
              // onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}
            />
          </ModalWrapper>
        </animated.div>
      </Background>
    ) : null}
  </>
);
};
```

So right now the ref is attached to the background, but if I `console.log(modalRef.current)` it will show me the entire jsx with all my children divs inside, but I only want to target the outside div aka the background

So whenever I click outside of my modal it will close

Note: when I console.log(modalRef.current) this is what shows up in the console aka my entire JSX

[image]

I'm also using styled-components, so I only want to target the top div which I called `Background` but shows `sc-bdnylx iEsAwc` so I have no idea how to target it since it doesn't have any ids or classNames

I tried to add this  `console.log(modalRef.current.children[0])` but when I implemented it into my function, it didn't work properly. This console.log does only show the divs below my `Background` div, but I haven't found anything about targeting just the `Background` only

Comment: have you tried comparing the target to the ref? e.g. `if (modalRef.current === e.target) {`

Comment: ah thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use refs here. Just add `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to one of the divs inside `Background`, like on ModalWrapper. It'll stop the click from passing through.

Comment: is there a benefit of using this over useRef?

Comment: Not massively... I just find it a little cleaner, and it's less code/variables.

Comment: would it affect the app if it gets bigger and you'd need to make sure you're targeting the right thing? Or that wouldn't matter?

Comment: It wouldn't really matter. I normally put the `e.stopPropagation()` inside the element I'm clicking on. It would amount to the same thing if you used a ref in that handler to check the clicked element equals a particular ref.